# Why does Python use exceptions to manage iterators, and why don't other languages?

Tags: python, iterator, language-design, python-internals

In Java, iterators have a `hasNext()` method (if I recall correctly -- it's been a long time since I programmed in Java, so the details may be off). When you're stepping through an iterator, you query `hasNext()` to see if you should stop.

In Python, there is no `hasNext()`, and iterators instead raise the `StopIteration` exception when they want to signal that you should stop. Why the difference?

I could imagine that not requiring `hasNext()` makes less work for whoever's implementing the iterator; in that case, why do Java and other languages use it? Is it a philosophical difference, or are exceptions for some reason easier/faster in Python?

Comment: Relevant: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/112463/why-do-iterators-in-python-raise-an-exception

Comment: @ajcr: Thanks! I'll look on Programmers first for these kind of questions in the future. This question isn't, I feel, a duplicate of what it is currently marked as a duplicate of, but it is a duplicate of the question at your link (and I am now enlightened). Can we get it changed for posterity?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about language design, which is better suited (and [already answered](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/112463/why-do-iterators-in-python-raise-an-exception)) on Programmers.

Answer (score 0):

`StopIteration` is more often used by generator (keyword `yield`) rather than iterator. Generator uses the exception to indicate to the caller that a sequence has been exhausted.

In addition, taking advantage of exception is an common idiom of python language. A good example is the detection of a float number string. It is commonly written this way in python:

```
def is_float(in_num):
    try:
        float(in_num)
        return true
    except ValueError:
        return false
```

Comment: My impression was that every iterator raises `StopIteration` when it's out of elements. For example, if you execute `it = iter('abc'); next(it); next(it); next(it); next(it)` you get a `StopIteration`. Good point about ask-for-forgiveness, I hadn't considered that.